# Property initialisation order Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have 2 classes, A and B in Typescript. B derives from A, A's constructor calls function `init` and B overrides `init`.
a.ts

```
export default class A {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        console.log("A.init()")
    }
}
```

b.ts

```
import A from "./a"

export default class B extends A {
    public bx = 3;
    public by = 10;
    public bz = 0;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    init(){
        this.bx = 5;
        this.bz = this.by;
        console.log("B.init()")
    }
}
```

The js files compiled by `tsc` were like

a.js

```
export default class A {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        console.log("A.init()");
    }
}
```

b.js

```
import A from "./a";
export default class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.bx = 3;
        this.by = 10;
        this.bz = 0; //even worse
    }
    init() {
        this.bx = 5;
        this.bz = this.by;
        console.log("B.init()");
    }
}
```

No surpise in `a.js`. But in `b.js`, we can see a line `this.bx = 3;` after `super()` in the constructor. While I agree it is necessary to initialise a property like `this.bx = 3;` which is a declaration in the class, **I simply cannot understand why in this case, it has `this.bx=3;` after `super()` even theoretically the compiler should be able to know `this.bx` has been set and is not uninitialised from the AST. **What's the consideration**?** It should only init a property if the property has never been assigned. In my case, I suppose it should be

```
import A from "./a";
export default class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    init() {
        this.bx = 3; // initialisation from the declaration can appear here before the first time use. It can be optimized because of the next line assignment
        this.bx = 5; // first time use `this.bx`
        this.by = 10; // the initialisation here is because this.by is used in the next line
        this.bz = this.by; 
        console.log("B.init()");
    }
}
```

Compare to c#

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.Out.Write("x: " + b.x + " y: " + b.y);
    }
}

class A {
    public A() {
        init();
    }
    
    public virtual void init() {
    }
}

class B : A {
    public int x = 3;
    public int y = 10;
    public int z = 4;
    public B() : base() {
    }
    
    public override void init() {
        this.x = 5;
        this.y = this.z;
    }
}
```

You will get `x: 5 y: 4`.

Answer (score 1):

There are very sound reasons to ensure that your base class is **fully initialized** before initialization of the extended sub class happens, and this is mandated in the MDN documentation for `super`:

> [When used in a constructor, the super keyword appears alone and **must be used before the this keyword is used**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

By having your base class call an overridden method in its constructor that fiddles with properties of `this` of the subclass, you've messed up the order of initialization. By violating this important requirement, any assumptions that compilers make on the back of this requirement are now broken.

Mayhem follows...

The most preferable outcome here would be a fat compilation error.

Comment: I agree! That can be a good reason. I'd recommend `tsc` warns if a virtual function is called in the constructor. Unless other people has better solutions.